# My C program is taking only one input instead of multiple input

Tags: c, arguments, function-call, function-declaration

I am a beginner and I am learning the C programming language. I am trying to make a program of two matrices that will take input and show output.

I have written a C program for that but it is taking only one input. After taking one input the program is terminating automatically.

Here is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void matrixInput(int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols], int matrixNo) {
  printf("Matrix %d input:\n", matrixNo);

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      printf("Matrix %d [%d, %d]: ", matrixNo, i + 1, j + 1);
      scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
    }
  }

  printf("\n");
}

void matrixDisplay(int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols], int matrixNo) {
  printf("Matrix %d output:\n", matrixNo);

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("\n");
}

int main() {
  int rows, columns;

  printf("Rows: ");
  scanf("%d", &rows);
  printf("Columns: ");
  scanf("%d", &columns);

  int matrix1[rows][columns], matrix2[rows][columns];

  matrixInput(matrix1, rows, columns, 1);
  matrixInput(matrix2, rows, columns, 2);
  
  matrixDisplay(matrix1, row, column, 1);
  matrixDisplay(matrix2, row, column, 2);

  return 0;
}
```

Why this is happening? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Turn on, **and mind**, your compiler warnings. You are calling `matrixInput()` with the arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: You should **never ever** use `scanf` or other I/O functions without checking the result.

Comment: Thank you so much. My bad. I found my fault. Now my program is working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void matrixInput(int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols], int matrixNo)
```

but you are calling

```
  matrixInput(matrix1, rows, columns, 1);
```

while it must be

```
  matrixInput(rows, columns,matrix1, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My bad. I found my fault. Now my program is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

The order of arguments in these calls

```
matrixInput(matrix1, rows, columns, 1);
matrixInput(matrix2, rows, columns, 2);

matrixDisplay(matrix1, row, column, 1);
matrixDisplay(matrix2, row, column, 2);
```

does not corresponds to the order of the function parameter declarations

```
void matrixInput(int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols], int matrixNo) {
```

and

```
void matrixDisplay(int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols], int matrixNo) {
```

Moreover in the last two calls there are typos in the used identifiers. Instead of `row` and `column` you need to use `rows` and `columns`.

You need to write the function calls like for example

```
matrixInput(rows, columns, matrix1, 1);
```